# Reducing number of time series in VECM

Tags: feature-selection, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am exploring using VECM for several time series that are all I(1). However, I am hoping to avoid a model that is too large and was wondering if there is any way I can filter out several variables before performing the cointegration tests. Does it make sense to use stepwise regression and regress the first difference of the main variable of interest on the first differences of the other variables to determine which to keep in the VECM?